# Creating a simple 'hello world' and linking it together with 2 pre-compiled objects

Tags: c++, c, linker, dev-c++, object-files

In my created project I got "IGEL1.OBJ" and "IGEL2.OBJ" as well as "IGEL.H".

In Orwell Dev-C++ I take the following steps:

> 1. 'File'->'New'->'Project...'
> 2. Register 'Basic'->'Console Application'->'C Project'
> 3. 'Name:'->IgelTest->'OK'.

Then under the 'Project' register

> 1. right-click on 'IgelTest'
> 2. 'Add to project'

Adding consequently

> - IGEL1.OBJ
> - IGEL2.OBJ
> - IGEL.H

Once I've done this I go to

> 1. 'Project'
> 2. 'Project Options'
> 3. Register 'Files'
> 4. left-click on 'IGEL1.OBJ'
> 5. check 'Include in linking' under 'Files'
> 6. repeat the same for 'IGEL2.OBJ'
> 7. left-click 'OK'

Now I've got 'main.c' in my view, click on the 'Compile & Run' button, and receive the following error message:
mingw32-make.exe: *** No rule to make target 'IGEL1.o', needed by 'IgelTest.exe'.  Stop.

I've uploaded the project folder here:
https://mega.co.nz/#F!ggpWEJIK!bHu30zK8y4UXU-LoAdcddQ

Here's a pastebin of 'Makefile.win':
http://pastebin.com/Pr9iS3Wc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look in your `Makefile.win` you will see that it thinks the object files to be
linked are:

```
LINKOBJ  = main.o IGEL1.o IGEL2.o
```

and also that there are indeed no rules for making `IGEL1.o`, `IGEL2.o`. Your object files
`IGEL1.OBJ` and `IGEL2.OBJ` are not mentioned at all.

For the compiler you are using - GCC for Windows - object files conventionally have the extension `.o`, not `.obj`.

If you add any file *name.extension* to a Dev-C++ project and check it for *Include in linking*, then if Dev-C++ doesn't recognize *.extension* as an extension of files that can be linked, it thinks the file is some sort of *source* file and you want to link the object file *name.o* that is compiled from it.

That is what happens with your `.obj` files. The makefile contains no rules for making 
`IGEL1.o`, `IGEL2.o` because the IDE knows no way to make a `.o` file from a `.obj` file.

To solve this problem, rename your `.obj` files with extension `.o`. Then the linkage
*may* work. It still *won't* work, however, if your pre-compiled `.obj` files are in 32-bit format and your version of Dev-C++ is the one that uses the TDM GCC 64-bit toolchain. Then you will get a different sort of linkage error, and to solve that you will need to recompile your `.obj` files as 64-bit `.o` files from source.